# Parameter estimation for Stochastic differential equation

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, parameter-estimation

I have a process $X(t)$ defined on some finite time horizon $[0,T]$ and I know that my process satisfies the following SDE:

$dX(t)=X_t \mu dt + X_t \sigma dB_t$.

where $B$ is a standard Brownian motion. In particular I'm assuming that both the drift and volatility are constant over time.

**Question**:

Given data points $x_{t_1}, \ldots x_{t_n}$ that are realizations of the random variable $X(t)$ at times $t_1 \ldots t_n$, how do I estimate the drift and volatility parameters $\mu, \sigma$ ? I'm interested in a method that is relatively easy to implement.

I would also like to know if there already exist libraries in say Python that might help for this task.

What would be a method for estimating $\mu$ and $\sigma$ if they change over time? (I.e. they are are time dependent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For geometric Brownian motion we have (by solving the SDE)
$$\log X_{t_i}=\log X_{t_{i-1}}+\tilde\mu(t_i-t_{i-1})+\sigma(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}}),\quad i=1,..,n$$
where $\tilde\mu=\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$.
Hence the conditional distribution of $X_{t_i}$ given $X_{t_{i-1}}$ is log-normal with mean equal to $\log X_{t_{i-1}}+\tilde\mu(t_i-t_{i-1})$ and variance $\sigma^2 (t_i-t_{i-1})$.
Suppose that $X_0=x_0$ is fixed (the calculations are very similar if $X_0$ is itself lognormal, just add another term), the log of the joint density of the vector $(X_{t_1},...,X_{t_n})$ at $x_1,...,x_n$ takes the following form:
$$\log p(x_1,...,x_n)=-\sum_{i=1}^n\log x_i-\frac{n}{2}\log 2\pi\sigma^2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\log\Delta t_i-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(\log x_i-\log x_{i-1}-\tilde\mu\Delta t_i)^2}{\sigma^2\Delta t_i},$$
where we introduced $\Delta t_i=t_i-t_{i-1}$.
Differentiating this wrt. $\mu$, we obtain
$$\partial_{\tilde\mu}\log p=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\Big(\log x_n-\log x_0-\tilde\mu(t_n-t_0)\Big)=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\tilde\mu=\frac{\log x_n-\log x_0}{t_n-t_0},$$
and by using this, we can also solve the other equation:
$$\partial_{\sigma^2}\log p=\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\Big(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(\log x_i-\log x_{i-1}-\tilde\mu\Delta t_i)^2}{\Delta t_i}-n\Big)=0$$
$$\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\sigma^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(\log x_i-\log x_{i-1}-\tilde\mu\Delta t_i)^2}{\Delta t_i}.$$

Comment: Indeed, I found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554579/transition-density-of-a-geometric-brownian-motion. Or, maybe better, equation (14) here: file:///C:/Users/Me/Downloads/SSRN-id2944341.pdf . So it would be enough to maximize the likelihood function with respect to $\mu$ and $\sigma$ right? This can be done in python, there are some optimiztion packages. or

Comment: But that is for a different SDE (geometric Brownian motion). What you have is Brownian motion with drift.

Comment: You are totally right, I did a mistake in writing down the formula. I am considering geometric brownian motion, will fix that now.

Comment: Ok, in that case you can do the same with just a couple of logs. I will change my answer. You don't need any optimization packages. You can solve for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ algebraically!

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: could you change your answer and maybe show how to solve for optimal $\mu$ and $\sigma$  so that I can accept your answer?

Comment: I think it should be $\log x_i -\log x_{i-1} - \widetilde{\mu}\Delta t_i$ in the brackets and not $x_i - x_{i-1} -\widetilde{\mu}\Delta t_i$,right? Also I think you forgot to consider the $x_i$ term which comes from the denominator of the density function of the log normal distribution.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I made the corrections, hope everything is correct now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so familiar with this formulation of the problem, but a common practice in engineering is the method based on [Allan Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_variance). You basically assume the high frequency noise to be the volatility while the low frequency is the drift and identify btoh from the slopes on the chart..

As for the case when they are not constant it would be necessary to make some assumptions on how they vary over time. Either by giving them specific time functions with parameters to be estimated or possibly assuming that they are themselves performing soem kind of random (possibly Brownian) motion, in which case some technique like an [Extended Kalman Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter) or a [Particle Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter) could be envisaged.