# Approximation of the maximum likelihood estimate for the drift and volatility in a stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation, stochastic-differential-equations

So if I have the stochastic differential equation

$dX(t) = \mu dt + \sigma dW(t)$,

I know the maximum likelihood estimate for the drift and volatility is:

\begin{align}
&\hat{\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{N\Delta t}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}} X(t_{n+1}) - X(t_n)\\
&\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{\Delta t (N-1)}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} (X(t_{n+1}) - X(t_n) - \hat{\mu}\Delta t)^2
\end{align}
However my question is if the equation changes slightly

$dX(t) = \mu X(t) dt + \sigma X(t) dW(t)$,

are the previous estimates of drift and volatility consistent with this new equation?

I found my question here : [Parameter estimation for Stochastic differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985791/parameter-estimation-for-stochastic-differential-equation) , and it seems yes, but it is not explicitly said.

In general if I have a process that satisfies:

$dX(t) = f_1(X(t),\mu)dt + f_2(X(t),\sigma) d W(t)$,
are the above estimates always valid for approximating the drift and volatility parameters (assuming that $f_1,f_2$ smooth functions).

Thank you